# Jquery image swap navigation issue

Tags: jquery, image, onclick

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(document).ready(function() {

$j("img.sswap").click(function() {
      $j("img.sswap").each(function() {
            this.src = this.src.replace("_on", "_off");
      });
      this.src = this.src.replace("_on", "_off");
});

});
</script>

<div id="navigation">
<ul>
<li><a href="#d1"><img class="sswap" src="img/d1_off.png"></a></li>
<li><a href="#d2"><img class="sswap" src="img/d2_off.png"></a></li>
<li><a href="#d3"><img class="sswap" src="img/d3_off.png"></a></li>
<li><a href="#d4"><img class="sswap" src="img/d4_off.png"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you are not explaining your problem

Comment: What happens when you run this?
BTW, correct the second line of your code. Should be
**jQuery(document).ready(...**

Comment: As far as parsing errors it seems to work (some problem with getting the correct jQuery sign ($), otherwise it seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/k4qzU/1/ . Not really sure what you're trying to accomplish tough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to toggle the on/off state of a single image then Alfie-101's answer will work for you.  However, from reading your code, it looks like you may only want one image to be "on" at a time.  it seems like you're trying to turn "off" all images and then turn "on" the clicked image.  The biggest problem in your code is that your last line should be replacing "off" to "on" instead of "on" to "off.  So, if you want all images to be "off" then change your code to the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img.sswap").click(function() {
        $("img.sswap").each(function() {
            this.src = this.src.replace("_on", "_off");
        });
        this.src = this.src.replace("_off", "_on");
    });
});
```

**Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z8WNZ/**

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I need to do but it's not working, I am getting and error "object expected line 2" and the images aren't changing.

Comment: No!  I didn't see it but i do know and it works!!!  Hallelujah  LOL  Thank yo uso much :)

So the issue was the  $(window).load(function(){ instead of  $(document).load(function(){  ?

Comment: So I am posting your answer for othe people like me:

Comment: @mark: Nice.  If it is working for you, don't forget to click the little checkmark to the left of this question :-)

Comment: <script type='text/javascript'>
  $(window).load(function(){
  $("img.sswap").click(function() {
      $("img.sswap").each(function() {
            this.src = this.src.replace("_on", "_off");
      });
      this.src = this.src.replace("_off", "_on");
});



  });
   
  </script>
  
</head>
<body>
  <div id="navigation">
<ul>
<li><a href="#d1"><img class="sswap" src="img_swap_off.png"></a></li>
<li><a href="#d2"><img class="sswap" src="img_swap_off.png"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

Comment: I did thanks again.  Tried to join a few times so I can mark things as helpful but I keep getting an error on registration.

Comment: Too bad.  Keep giving it a shot.  The more you participate in the site, the better.

Comment: If you have a gmail account, try using that.  It seems to work pretty flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you actually want to happen, this code would appear to swap every image *except* the one that was clicked. First, you loop through everything that matched the same selector as the bind and swap it. Then you re-swap the one that was clicked, restoring it to it's original state.

I can't believe that's what you actually want to happen, probably you should remove the `each` loop.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navigation">
<ul>
<li><a href="#d1"><img class="sswap" src="img/d1_off.png"></a></li>
<li><a href="#d2"><img class="sswap" src="img/d2_off.png"></a></li>
<li><a href="#d3"><img class="sswap" src="img/d3_off.png"></a></li>
<li><a href="#d4"><img class="sswap" src="img/d4_off.png"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $("img.sswap").toggle(
        function() { 
        var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("_off", "_on");
        $(this).attr("src", src);
    },
    function() {
        var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("_on", "_off");
        $(this).attr("src", src);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Nope, no luck.  Tried it in ie and mozilla.  Ugh!  Why is this so difficult??  I just want to swap and image and have it stay while selected.

Comment: This does work are you including this `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` in `<head>`